# Temporarily preserve changes with javascript in a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to do a proof of concept and wrote a function that replaces values and styles in my current webpage with `JavaScript`

example;

```
const headerColor = document.getElementById("topheader");
headerColor.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
headerColor.style.background = 'none';
```

I am wondering if I can save all these in a cookie or so in order to create a demo with those styles throughout a checkout process.

For example, I am temporarily replacing the header of a page with `JavaScript` and would like to preserve that in a cookie for the remainder of the session.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, create cookies like `backgroundColor=white` and `background=none`. Then when the script starts, check for the cookies and set the styles.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will copy to/from the styles to cookies, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: @Barmar your referring to something like this?  document.cookie = backgroundColor = white?

Comment: Something like that, but it needs to be in quotes and no spaces. `document.cookie = 'backgroundColor=white'`

Comment: Why? We already have `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`, just use those. Cookies kind of make absolutely no sense here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you, can you give me an example as to how i could use that using sessionStorage or localStorage?

Comment: you look up how to use them, and then do. They're both string value stores, one is tied to "this tab only" and the other to "any tab/window for this site". You set values with `.set(keyname, value)`, and you get data back out with `.get(keyname)`. So just make a config object, and then save that as JSON in either Storage and then take check for it and take it out if it's there on page load. Also: don't set styling on HTML elements, use CSS classes. And _build_ those classes and create a <link rel="stylesheet"> with a data-uri, if they're dynamic. Don't mess with `element.style`.